# File attachment type

Tags: php, email, sendmail, attachment

Hi i have code that sends email with multiple attachments, but i have problems with one piece of that code below.

Whenever i submit image, i get "Unsuported file format!". If i delete that part of code, it works great, but then user can send every type of file (that is dangerous, i know). Filesize check works great. What is wrong? :S

```
//*** Attachment ***//  
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"]);$i++)  
{
    $filesize = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["size"][$i]/1024;

    if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i] != "" && $filesize < 50 && preg_match("image/", $_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"][$i]))  
    {  
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"][$i];  
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"][$i])));  
    $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
    $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
    $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
    }
    elseif(!preg_match("image/", $_FILES["fileAttach"]["type"][$i])){
        die('<div id="warning">Unsuported file format!</div>');
    }
    elseif($filesize > 50){
        die('<div id="warning">Filesize must be less than 2 Mb!!!</div>');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";
```

should just be

```
$strHeader .= "Content-type: application/octet-stream\n";
```

with no filename portion. That goes onto the content-disposition line.

In the bigger picture view, don't build your own mime emails. As you're finding out, it's painful and ugly. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to do it for you - that whole attachment business can be reduced to a **SINGLE** function call with either library.

Comment: Well, tnx, i will use it for future projects. But i cant heavily modify existing project (on many sites), so i am trying to solve this "bug" somehow, but i just cant figure it out.